# session maintenance in server and android app

Tags: java, android, connection, session-cookies

I am developing an app which interacts with server (set up locally) . user logs in and accesses his data. In order to do that a session has to me maintained . I am facing problem how to implement it on server as well as client side (app). Please help me with dis.please suggest me any example codes / method to proceed.

Note:
I do know how to send requests and getting responses.

Answer (score 1):

Please see the steps below:

- User tries to login to the app, the login request is sent.
- the server gets the request and adds the user in the DB and provides a session id, which is sent to the user app via API response.
- The user at the app side can save this session in shared preference and can maintain the session until a logout request is called.
- On Logout clear the session id for that user in DB and from shared preference on the app side.
- On the next login a new session is issued and the cycle continues.